# How to pass a parameter from angularjs file to a mvc controller

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, controller

I want to save textbox value to a .dat file.

this is my button click :

```
<input type="button" id="btnSave" name="btnSave" value="Save" data-ng-click="PostSensor(sensor)" />
```

sensor is the parameter contains the textbox value.

here is my controller.js file

```
    $scope.PostSensor = function (sensor) {
    alert("Post Sensor");
    debugger;
    var result = SensorService.PostSensor(sensor);
    result.then(function (response) {
        $scope.result = response.data;

    });
```

and Here is my service.js

```
 this.PostSensor = function (sensor) {
    alert("service post");
    alert(JSON.stringify(sensor));
    var result = $http.post("Demo/PostSensor", JSON.stringify(sensor));
    return result;
};
```

The alert(JSON.stringify(sensor)); shows correct value.

my Controller.vb file is

```
 <HttpPost()>
Public Function PostSensor(ByVal objsensordata As Sensors) As Boolean
   Try
        objDemoService.Save(objsensordata)
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try

End Function
```

my problem is ***objsensordata*** value is nothing. some problem while passing the value from **service.js to controller.vb**

Can anyone help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Please give me a solution

Comment: Hi Nayan, Please compare the dataType and fieldName of "Sensors" Class and JSON.stringify(sensor) object. It seems some datatype or fieldName mismatch